# SQL Server XML Extract Nodes

Tags: xml, database, sql-server-2005, openxml

I am using SQL Server 2005 to Extract XML data. I would appreciate some help extracting the following XML snippet?

```
<ELEMENT_A>
    <CHILD_A _attribA="ABC">
       <CHILD_B Type="1">
          <CHILD_C>
             <CHILD_D Type="1" Date="2010-08-31">
                <CHILD_E _attribB="M0">
                   <CHILD_F>-0.32295</CHILD_F>
                </CHILD_E>
            </CHILD_D>
         </CHILD_C>
     </CHILD_B>
   </CHILD_A>
</ELEMENT_A>
```

> How do I get the data in the following tabular format?
>   ELEMENT_A  | _attribA |  CHILD_A |  CHILD_B | CHILD_C | CHILD_D | CHILD_E | CHILD_F
>
> Note: I'd like to use select by nodes e.g. the following gets me the value of the first Attribute:
>   select
>           v.value('@_attribA[1]','nvarchar(4)')
>       from @doc.nodes('/ELEMENT_A/CHILD_A') x(v)

Very much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You're missing a closing <CHILD_A> tag in your sample

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is not too late for you. I saw your question just today

```
select 
v.value('../../../../../@_attribA','nvarchar(4)')  as _attribA
,v.value('../../@Date','nvarchar(12)') as [Date]
,v.value('../@_attribB','nvarchar(2)') as _attribB
,v.value('.','float') as CHILD_F
,v.query('../../../../..') as CHILD_A

from @doc.nodes('/ELEMENT_A/CHILD_A/CHILD_B/CHILD_C/CHILD_D/CHILD_E/CHILD_F') x(v)
```